# linux command prompt ftp to ftp server running on windows

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp, file-transfer, filezilla

I am using on Windows Vista, Filezilla server. I have it set up to be accessed via outside IPs and when I use a client on the IP I have it connects normally using Filezilla client. On the same machine I have Ubuntu running in a virtual box and when using filezilla client in there it works fine. Now I want to try the command prompt. So I do the

```
ftp xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

I enter the name and password and i get the ftp command prompt, but the commands are not working properly. when trying "ls" or "cd" these commands do not work. "cd" tells me that the current directory is "/" root, but this does not make sense in the windows operating system.

Now the filezilla client is taking the user in the application window directly to the root folder of the permitted filespace granted to that user. How can the same be done from the command prompt, if there is a way? It is as if the command prompt takes me to the root which does not exist or even have correct permissions to move in. Is there any way to be taken to the correct directory directly, or move there especially when the slashes are the wrong way around etc?

Best,

Comment: Re "the slashes are the wrong way around": Windows has accepted `/` as a directory separator since at least Windows 95.

Answer (score 1):

The command-line `ftp` is working properly, and taking you to the **root** of the folder that FileZilla Server is configured to serve. If you look (more) closely at the FileZilla Client, you can see that it, in fact, does read `/` when you connect.

Comment: but I cannot do "ls"

Answer (score 0):

It’s not the root of the UNIX file system / it’s / as far back as you can go up the tree. I often connect to a UNIX FTP server via the console FTP client in W7, easy as a UNIX one just need to use native FTP commands. Also note that CMD doesn’t not like spaces in directories so remember to “quote” them.

Cd / or simply cd .. until you can’t go back.